# Upgrade MySQL Version, need I also upgrade the database as well?

Tags: mysql, upgrade, format

I am running MySQL 5.6.51. And I notice that there is MySQL 8.x. Based on https://severalnines.com/database-blog/tips-for-upgrading-mysql-5-7-to-mysql-8, I need to first upgrade from 5.6.x to 5.7.x, then to MySQL 8.x.

My question is, during the first phrase or second phrase of upgrade, will the database in my server also be upgraded as well? Or need I upgrade the database format to match the version of MySQL manually?

Comment: The databases will be upgraded alongside MySQL. Make sure that you have a proper backup, though, as there is no downgrade path.

Comment: Recommend reading [official 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading.html) and [8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html) documentation

Comment: Did you run `mysql_upgrade`?